# Limit ignored when used with find_by_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, rails-activerecord

I am trying to understand a behaviour of Rails ActiveRecord with [`limit`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-limit).

Let's say I have a model `Car` with only one attribute `name`.

Now in the console (`rails console`), if I type:

```
Car.limit(0).where(name: 'foo')
```

I get

```
SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE "cars"."name" = 'foo' LIMIT 0
```

which is correct, but:

```
Car.limit(0).find_by_id(1)
```

gives

```
SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE "cars"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Why is the `limit` option ignored?

Note that

```
Car.where(name:'foo').find_by_id(1)
```

gives

```
SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE "cars"."name" = 'foo' AND "cars"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
```

So `find_by_id`(or `find`) ignores `limit` but accepts `where`? How do you explain that?

*Sidenote*

I know that these queries don't make sense. I have an edge case in a project which executes `Car.limit(0).find_by_id(1)`, the expected result was to get a nil object. I am trying to understand why `find_by_id` or `find` ignores `limit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` and `find_by_` are methods used to retrieve a single instance. The result is either one object or nil if there are no objects to be found.

Because the method is supposed to return only one object it sets the limit to 1 regardless of what limit you specify.

If you want to specify a limit, use where as per your example.

Comment: Sounds reasonable enough. Thanks!